# How to define a macro describing a memory location?

Tags: c, macros

A variable is located in memory at address 0x10000. How can I define a macro such that writing to that macro writes to that memory location?

Comment: The question as stated isn't particularly clear. Do you want to create a macro that can be used like `MACRO = value` or do you want to create a macro that can be used like `MACRO(value)`? You've also not indicated what you've tried, and as a result we don't know where you're having problems. You should probably start with some code that accomplishes this **without** a macro, and then turning that into a macro.

Comment: I am also confused when I read this question. Its an interview aptitude question. I haven't changed the question(except someone edited the question now).  I just want figure out 2 things from this question. 1) How an expert in c and macro interpret this question and 2) of course the answer itself. I find it difficult to understand too.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The de facto standard way of declaring a writeable memory location in C is this:

```
#define REGISTER (*(volatile uint8_t*)0x10000)
```

where `uint8_t` should correspond to the size of the contents at that memory location.

And then `REGISTER = something;` writes to that memory location, just as if REGISTER was a variable.

It is important to use the `volatile` keyword, to prevent optimization bugs and ensuring that reads of the location are always up to date.

Comment: Thanks for the answer @Lundin one more question, how could i display the value copied to that macro?

Comment: @runner The same way you would display any other variable. Only down side with macros like these is that you can't get a "watchable" object in a debugger - why some toolchains provide non-standard ways to declare variables at specific memory locations. Shouldn't be a problem though, since every decent debugger has an option to display a memory map where you can scroll to the specific address.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
#define WRITE_TO_0X10000(v) (*((char *)0x10000) = (char)(v))
```

You didn't defined what kind of value should be written, I supposed that a byte is to be written. The macro does the following :

1. convert the value 0x10000 to a pointer to char `((char *)0x10000)`
2. force the value to be a char (8-bits) `((char)(v))`
3. write the value to the memory pointed `*pointer = value`

Another possibility is:

```
#define POINTER_TO_0x10000 ((char *)0x10000)
*POINTER_TO_0X10000 = some_char_value
```

You can easily adapt to any other type you need.

Comment: possibly also `#define VAR_TO_0X10000 (*(char*)0x10000)` if I understood OPs intent correctly.

Comment: Never use the `char` type for things like this since it has implementation-defined signedness.